# Apache UIMA: modify dictionary annotators at run-time

Tags: apache, dictionary, uima

Apache UIMA dictionaries* are compile-time objects. 
Dictionaries must be pre-defined.

Is there any mechanism to **add entries** to dictionaries **at run-time**?
Any pattern or workaround?

*as implemented by IBM Watson Explorer Content Analytics

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The dictionaries are loaded at the first use of the engine. What I did in a previous project was that I add a filewatch to the directory that contains all the ruta logic (ruta scripts and additional resources) and at a change event, I started in a background thread a new engine. After the new engine is loaded I send a dummy request into the engine (so everything is initialized) and when that's completed I replaced the live engine with the new engine.

With that approach we had a system where we can did live updates to  ruleset. (scripts, configuration and dictionary entries)